# combining three arrays to generate tree like structure of data

Tags: javascript

If I have the following data as shown below:

```js
var data = [{
    "EmployeeID": 2,
    "FirstName": "Andrew",
    "LastName": "Fuller",
    "Country": "USA",
    "Title": "Vice President, Sales",
    "HireDate": "1992-08-14 00:00:00",
    "BirthDate": "1952-02-19 00:00:00",
    "City": "Tacoma",
    "Address": "908 W. Capital Way",
    "expanded": "true",
    children: [{
            "EmployeeID": 8,
            "FirstName": "Laura",
            "LastName": "Callahan",
            "Country": "USA",
            "Title": "Inside Sales Coordinator",
            "HireDate": "1994-03-05 00:00:00",
            "BirthDate": "1958-01-09 00:00:00",
            "City": "Seattle",
            "Address": "4726 - 11th Ave. N.E."
        },
        {
            "EmployeeID": 1,
            "FirstName": "Nancy",
            "LastName": "Davolio",
            "Country": "USA",
            "Title": "Sales Representative",
            "HireDate": "1992-05-01 00:00:00",
            "BirthDate": "1948-12-08 00:00:00",
            "City": "Seattle",
            "Address": "507 - 20th Ave. E.Apt. 2A"
        },
        {
            "EmployeeID": 3,
            "FirstName": "Janet",
            "LastName": "Leverling",
            "Country": "USA",
            "Title": "Sales Representative",
            "HireDate": "1992-04-01 00:00:00",
            "BirthDate": "1963-08-30 00:00:00",
            "City": "Kirkland",
            "Address": "722 Moss Bay Blvd."
        },
        {
            "EmployeeID": 4,
            "FirstName": "Margaret",
            "LastName": "Peacock",
            "Country": "USA",
            "Title": "Sales Representative",
            "HireDate": "1993-05-03 00:00:00",
            "BirthDate": "1937-09-19 00:00:00",
            "City": "Redmond",
            "Address": "4110 Old Redmond Rd."
        },
        {
            "EmployeeID": 5,
            "FirstName": "Steven",
            "LastName": "Buchanan",
            "Country": "UK",
            "Title": "Sales Manager",
            "HireDate": "1993-10-17 00:00:00",
            "BirthDate": "1955-03-04 00:00:00",
            "City": "London",
            "Address": "14 Garrett Hill",
            "expanded": "true",
            children: [{
                    "EmployeeID": 6,
                    "FirstName": "Michael",
                    "LastName": "Suyama",
                    "Country": "UK",
                    "Title": "Sales Representative",
                    "HireDate": "1993-10-17 00:00:00",
                    "BirthDate": "1963-07-02 00:00:00",
                    "City": "London",
                    "Address": "Coventry House Miner Rd."
                },
                {
                    "EmployeeID": 7,
                    "FirstName": "Robert",
                    "LastName": "King",
                    "Country": "UK",
                    "Title": "Sales Representative",
                    "HireDate": "1994-01-02 00:00:00",
                    "BirthDate": "1960-05-29 00:00:00",
                    "City": "London",
                    "Address": "Edgeham Hollow Winchester Way"
                },
                {
                    "EmployeeID": 9,
                    "FirstName": "Anne",
                    "LastName": "Dodsworth",
                    "Country": "UK",
                    "Title": "Sales Representative",
                    "HireDate": "1994-11-15 00:00:00",
                    "BirthDate": "1966-01-27 00:00:00",
                    "City": "London",
                    "Address": "7 Houndstooth Rd."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}];

console.log(data);
```

For each `children` property an parent, I have separate Ajax Calls which are returning me an array. Is it possible to combine three arrays that would generate an array as shown in the fiddle?

Original source of above data is [this](https://jseditor.io/?key=jqwidgets-tree-grid-template) and this is coming from [here](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtreegrid/index.htm)

**More explanation of what I want:**

I have 3 Arrays with me.

1. One array has data with `"EmployeeID": 2,` in it.
2. Second array has data containing `"EmployeeID": 8,1,3,4 and 5` which is the child of first array.
3. Third array containing `EmployeeID": 6,7 and 9` which is the child of second array.

All of the above arrays I am getting via an Ajax call (not shown above) and wondering if I can combine it in such a way, such that I could generate data in the format shown above.
The thing that is puzzling me is how to add `children: <my arra here>` as shown in the above format.

Comment: Please tell me more about this what exactly you want?

Comment: Also, reduce that code. You don't need _this_ much code to show off what you want. Strip all but the bare essential properties you need,

Comment: @AniketRaj Added more explanation. Please let me know if some thing isn't clear. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I added more explanation referring to. Hoping it's okay to keep that code now as my explanation depends upon that now.

Comment: @Tan Do you want to make this nested data flatten? Like in linear form?

Answer (score 0):

**Here you can try this logic:**

we can pass the data which has nested structure like :
**data->childrenArray->data->childrenArray and so on** in MakeNestedInLinear(data) it will return the flatten result in single array (linear data)

```js
var data = [
  {
    EmployeeID: 2,
    FirstName: "Andrew",
    LastName: "Fuller",
    Country: "USA",
    Title: "Vice President, Sales",
    HireDate: "1992-08-14 00:00:00",
    BirthDate: "1952-02-19 00:00:00",
    City: "Tacoma",
    Address: "908 W. Capital Way",
    expanded: "true",
    children: [
      {
        EmployeeID: 8,
        FirstName: "Laura",
        LastName: "Callahan",
        Country: "USA",
        Title: "Inside Sales Coordinator",
        HireDate: "1994-03-05 00:00:00",
        BirthDate: "1958-01-09 00:00:00",
        City: "Seattle",
        Address: "4726 - 11th Ave. N.E.",
      },
      {
        EmployeeID: 1,
        FirstName: "Nancy",
        LastName: "Davolio",
        Country: "USA",
        Title: "Sales Representative",
        HireDate: "1992-05-01 00:00:00",
        BirthDate: "1948-12-08 00:00:00",
        City: "Seattle",
        Address: "507 - 20th Ave. E.Apt. 2A",
      },
      {
        EmployeeID: 3,
        FirstName: "Janet",
        LastName: "Leverling",
        Country: "USA",
        Title: "Sales Representative",
        HireDate: "1992-04-01 00:00:00",
        BirthDate: "1963-08-30 00:00:00",
        City: "Kirkland",
        Address: "722 Moss Bay Blvd.",
      },
      {
        EmployeeID: 4,
        FirstName: "Margaret",
        LastName: "Peacock",
        Country: "USA",
        Title: "Sales Representative",
        HireDate: "1993-05-03 00:00:00",
        BirthDate: "1937-09-19 00:00:00",
        City: "Redmond",
        Address: "4110 Old Redmond Rd.",
      },
      {
        EmployeeID: 5,
        FirstName: "Steven",
        LastName: "Buchanan",
        Country: "UK",
        Title: "Sales Manager",
        HireDate: "1993-10-17 00:00:00",
        BirthDate: "1955-03-04 00:00:00",
        City: "London",
        Address: "14 Garrett Hill",
        expanded: "true",
        children: [
          {
            EmployeeID: 6,
            FirstName: "Michael",
            LastName: "Suyama",
            Country: "UK",
            Title: "Sales Representative",
            HireDate: "1993-10-17 00:00:00",
            BirthDate: "1963-07-02 00:00:00",
            City: "London",
            Address: "Coventry House Miner Rd.",
          },
          {
            EmployeeID: 7,
            FirstName: "Robert",
            LastName: "King",
            Country: "UK",
            Title: "Sales Representative",
            HireDate: "1994-01-02 00:00:00",
            BirthDate: "1960-05-29 00:00:00",
            City: "London",
            Address: "Edgeham Hollow Winchester Way",
          },
          {
            EmployeeID: 9,
            FirstName: "Anne",
            LastName: "Dodsworth",
            Country: "UK",
            Title: "Sales Representative",
            HireDate: "1994-11-15 00:00:00",
            BirthDate: "1966-01-27 00:00:00",
            City: "London",
            Address: "7 Houndstooth Rd.",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

function MakeNestedInLinear(data) {
  return data.reduce((acc, elem) => {
    let stack = [elem];
    while (stack.length) {
      let val = stack.shift();
      if (val && val.children) {
        stack.push(...val.children);
        delete val.children;
        acc.push(val);
      } else acc.push(val);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(MakeNestedInLinear(data));
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to build the data just like it is shown above if I have 3 arrays. such that  I can build a tree grid like it is shown in this example: https://jseditor.io/?key=jqwidgets-tree-grid-template